# Hide system provider, time and battery in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there any way to hide system info like provider, time and battery in ionic app?

They on the top, are they known as header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are known as status bar in the mobile programming terms

You can use the status bar plugin to hide the status from the application

If you are using ngCordova you can use 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/statusbar/ and hide the status bar as shown in the example: `$cordovaStatusbar.hide();`

else you can use the common Cordova plugin also for status bar: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar which has also a method to hide a status bar like `StatusBar.hide`